# Alfresco community edition workflow value passing to another workflow how?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco community edition-5.1.x , I have scenario sales and operations team filled details passing to HR Team get details search the candidates its kind of from one workflow triggering to start another workflow is possible ? and how?

Please find the data flow diagram[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please give us a use-case. I have difficulties to understand what you want.

Comment: I have update my questions ,Please help out

Comment: If I understood correctly, the HR team will find out some information during the workflow process and these information should be passed to Operations team. Please let me know, is that correct?

Comment: Yes it correct please give some suggestions

Comment: If it is in same workflow, you can use the execution variables to pass the values across the user tasks. Does it help you ?

Comment: If separate workflow is not possible ?

Comment: If it is two different workflow, it is very hard. Have you tried with sub-process and I didn't used the subprocess in activiti. You can refer sub-process here, http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnSubprocessAndCallActivity